# datatype character declaration (0.05D) why is the D not redundant after declaration?

Tags: vb.net, constants

I'm taking a Visual Basic class and I've been taught to use a type character after declaring a constant variable that is a decimal, like so:

```
const VARIABLE_NAME As Decimal = 0.06D
```

It seems redundant to me to add the `D` at the end, as I have already declared the data type. im afraid to ask my teacher, because i assume she probably wont be able to give me a clear answer in front of the class. I previously took a class on micro-processors so I have some (little) understating of how floats are stored in memory using binary. Can anyone give me a clear explanation so I can share it with my other classmates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data type you declare for your entity (a constant) is not necessarily the data type of the expression used to initialize that entity. You declare the type on the left side of the `=`, and it does not extend to the right. If the data types do not match, a conversion will need to happen upon assignment.

As [documented](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s9cz43ek.aspx), the type of a literal expression is dictated by its shape. A literal that falls under *Numeric, fractional part* is interpreted as a `Double` by default.

If you enable `Option Strict On` (which you should), the declaration

```
Const VARIABLE_NAME As Decimal = 0.06
```

will fail with the error:

> Option Strict On disallows implicit conversions from 'Double' to 'Decimal'.

This is because there is no implicit conversion from `Double` to `Decimal`, as the `Double` data type can possibly contain values that `Decimal` cannot represent.

To avoid the conversion, you provide a type character `D` that makes the literal `Decimal` in the first place.

---

Compare this to

```
Const VARIABLE_NAME As Decimal = 42
```

The left part is `Decimal`, the right part is `Integer`, but no compile error occurs even with `Option Strict On`, because now there is an implicit widening conversion from `Integer` to `Decimal`, because `Decimal` can represent all values an `Integer` can possibly have.

Comment: ok i kind of understand now, when you assign a fractional value to a variable, the value defaults to a double datatype, and throws up an error (if 'Option Strict On'). im sure there is some good reason for this. for some reason my teacher has told us to only use singles, and no doubles for our intro to VB class. for the sake of memory conservation i guess? shes a bit confusing.

Comment: @mholberger Not sure if you wrote the comment before or after I made some final edits. If you did it before, please find the explanation in the revised answer.

Comment: good thank you. studying the documentation for the decimal datatype now to grok in fullness. "Precision. Decimal is not a floating-point data type.The Decimal structure holds a binary integer value, together with a sign bit and an integer scaling factor that specifies what portion of the value is a decimal fraction. Because of this, Decimal numbers have a more precise representation in memory than floating-point types (Single and Double)."